# This code work only for video, not for streaming

Tags: java, android, live-streaming

My problem is reading videos and streaming on the net. If I know the location of a video file and I want to read it I just do:

```
String Url = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4";
VideoView videoView;
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById (R.id.loadVideo);
    videoView.setVideoURI (Uri.parse (this.Url));
    videoView.start ();
```

But if the video is a stream, for example sent from my computer, I know the address (example: 127.0.0.1:8080 , yeah is random example i know this is localhost and can't work in localhost, but i can't use the real address of video sorry) and I can play from windows via Vlc quietly, the video is not played, the code ends up "catch", then the same syntax can not be used for video streaming via http address.
I looked everywhere on the internet, but I did not find any working solution and many plugins seen are now obsolete and / or unusable with android studio. I'm not a professional Android programmer, but I've been asked to do it, do you know how I can do it?

I forgot: the intention is to create a live stream

Comment: What kind of “stream”? There are many kinds, and not all player can play all kinds.

Comment: Http stream or rtmp, must be one of two.

Comment: Should probably figure that out first.

Comment: It should be http, but not being the person who decides I can not say with certainty.

Comment: @szatmary I tried to do with WebView and it works but only the radio streaming, I can not open the videos, which on vlc can be seen.